# I have a DB that is locking up from numerous updates to a table: Should I convert it from MyISAM to InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, locking

FYI: I don't believe this is a duplicate question, I've looked and most are general questions with vague answers. See more specifics below:

Currently a database I am in charge of locks up every once in awhile to a state that becomes unresponsive, and I need to manually restart the MySQL server to make it become responsive again (Yuck). I believe the culprit is an UPDATE query that is being run, which is being called every 1 minute for each active user in the system.

The query is something like this:

```
UPDATE logging_table SET log_time = log_time + 60 WHERE id = X;
```

The table is not small (approx 0.5 million records) and is both updated and selected from quite often; it is a "Main operations" type table that is related to quite a few other tables (No FK's, just relations in the PHP framework we are using). The monitoring app I use shows the above query consuming about 40% of the overall database time in our app, followed by a SELECT query that gets information from that table.

Currently the table is MyISAM as it worked fine for a lower number of users, but as the active users participate during peak times of the day, the database locks up.

Does this sound like a table I should convert over to InnoDB (The rest of the tables were setup as MyISAM by default)? I should note that it is not feasible at this point to split this table so that frequent updates can happen on another table.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In almost every use case, InnoDB is preferred over MyISAM.  So, *yes*.

To make sure the indexes, etc are converted correctly, see if anything in [MySQL to InnoDB checklist](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) needs to be addressed.  Note that key_buffer_size should be decreased and innodb_buffer_pool_size increased.

In MyISAM, an UPDATE blocks all other operations on the *table*.  In InnoDB, it blocks only the one *row* (assuming the `WHERE` clause restricts the scope to a single row).

It is ok to have a mixture of MyISAM tables and InnoDB tables.